# How do I log exceptions into a file?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, logging

I'm having difficulty with one of my routes in production. I'm trying to diagnose errors
with the `logging` module:

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from logging import FileHandler, DEBUG
...

def create_app(script_info=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='', static_folder='')
    file_handler = FileHandler('./errorlog.txt')
    file_handler.setLevel(DEBUG)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    ...
    ...
    
    return app
```

blueprint route:

```
from flask import current_app
from datetime import datetime
...
...

@blog_blueprint.route('/contact', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def contact():
    ...
    ...
        requests.post('https://api.sendpulse.com/smtp/emails', data=json.dumps(data))
            response_obj['status'] = 'success'
            response_obj['message'] = 'message sent'
            return jsonify(response_obj), 200
        except Exception as e:
            current_app.logger.debug(f'{datetime.now()}: '+str(e))
            return jsonify(response_obj), 400
    else:
        current_app.logger.debug(f'{datetime.now()}, name: '+name)
        current_app.logger.debug(f'{datetime.now()}, email: '+email)
        current_app.logger.debug(f'{datetime.now()}, subject: '+subject)
        response_obj['message'] = 'unrecognized email provider'
        return jsonify(response_obj), 400
```

the `errorlog.txt` file is created but empty after testing the route. Any feedback is
much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the default **logging level** is higher than DEBUG.
Does it work if you do: `current_app.logger.warning("test")` ?

Then try setting the debug level like this:

```
current_app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Note that it is being done on the logger and not the handler.